# Display to two decimal places - React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display the results of a calculation to two decimal points.  The function I created has the behavior of taking an attribute from an object (the "amount" attribute) and will either add it to a starting balance (startBal) or will add it to the previous runningTotal attribute (runnigTotal).  After completeing this calculation, I want the result to display to two decimal places, as this is a finance application I am writing.

I am trying to use the .toFixed() method, but in reality I am not tied this method, I just want it to work.

Here is my main component.  The relevant function is addRunningTotal()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import TransactionSearch from './transactionSearch.js';
import PendingTransactions from './pendingTransactions.js';
import Transactions from './transactions.js';

class CheckingAccount extends Component {
  state = {
    startBal: 1000,
    pendingTransData: [
      { id: 0, date: '1/1/2020', transaction: "gas", amount: -25.45 },
      { id: 1, date: '1/2/2020', transaction: "cell phone", amount: -127.35 },
      { id: 2, date: '1/3/2020', transaction: "car payment", amount: -303.97, },
    ],
    transactionData: [
      {
        id: 0,
        date: '1/1/2020',
        transaction: "gas",
        amount: -35.45,
        runningTotal: null
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        date: '1/2/2020',
        transaction: "cell phone",
        amount: -227.35,
        runningTotal: null
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        date: '1/3/2020',
        transaction: "car payment",
        amount: -403.97,
        runningTotal: null
      },
    ]
  }

  addRunningTotal() {
    let { transactionData, startBal } = this.state

    console.log('start Balance: ', startBal);
    let prevAmount, running;
    transactionData.map((el, i) => {
      if (i === 0) {
        running = el.runningTotal = el.amount + startBal;
        prevAmount = el.runningTotal;

        console.log(running.toFixed(2))
        return running.toFixed(2);
      } else if (i > 0) {
        running = el.runningTotal = prevAmount + el.amount;
        prevAmount = el.runningTotal;

        console.log(running.toFixed(2))
        return running.toFixed(2);
      }
    });
    console.log('out of map function')
    console.log(transactionData);

    this.setState({ transactionData: transactionData, startBal: startBal });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addRunningTotal()
  }

  render() {
    let pendTransData = (
      <div>
        <h1>PendingTransactions</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Transaction</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        {this.state.pendingTransData.map((pendingTransData, index) => {
          return <PendingTransactions
            key={pendingTransData.id}
            date={pendingTransData.date}
            transaction={pendingTransData.transaction}
            amount={pendingTransData.amount} />
        })}
      </div>
    );

    let transData = (
      <div>
        <h1>Transaction Component</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Transaction</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Running Total</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
        {this.state.transactionData.map((transactionData, index) => {
          return <Transactions
            key={transactionData.id}
            date={transactionData.date}
            transaction={transactionData.transaction}
            amount={transactionData.amount}
            runningTotal={transactionData.runningTotal} />
        })}
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <h1> Checking Account</h1>
        <TransactionSearch />
        {pendTransData}
        {transData}
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default CheckingAccount;
```

Here is my child component.

```
import React from 'react';

function Transactions(props) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.date} </td>
      <td>{props.transaction}</td>
      <td>{props.amount}</td>
      <td>{props.runningTotal}</td>
    </tr>

  );
}

export default Transactions;
```

I expected to see the running total column displayed to two decimal places, but for some reason it displays to about 13 decimal places.  I am further confused because the console.log's I've used outputs to two decimal places.

Comment: Dont worry, this is a [common problem with certain languages](https://0.30000000000000004.com/). My advice is, use a [library](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) to handle this ops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you see more than two decimal places is that you set the `runningTotal` key of each element of `transactionData` to `running` without calling `toFixed`. You see your desired format when logging because you call `toFixed` when logging.

To fix this, I'd recommend removing `toFixed` from the `runningTotal` calculation entirely and only use `toFixed` in the `render` method, since it should only be used for presentation purposes.

Example:

```js
function Transactions(props) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{props.date} </td>
      <td>{props.transaction}</td>
      <td>{props.amount}</td>
      <td>{props.runningTotal.toFixed(2)}</td>
    </tr>

  );
}
```

Additionally, I'd recommend refactoring the `addRunningTotal` method to make it a bit more clear to read and avoid direct state manipulation. For example:

```js
addRunningTotal() {
  const { transactionData, startBal } = this.state;

  console.log('start Balance: ', startBal);
  let running = startBal;
  const transactionDataWithRunningTotals = transactionData.map(el => {
    running += el.amount;
    return {
      ...el,
      runningTotal: running,
    }
  });
  console.log('out of map function')
  console.log(transactionData);

  this.setState({ transactionData: transactionDataWithRunningTotals });
}
```

To handle the issue on the initial render, I would update your component to look something like this:

```js
class CheckingAccount extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      startBal: 1000,
      pendingTransData: [
        { id: 0, date: '1/1/2020', transaction: "gas", amount: -25.45 },
        { id: 1, date: '1/2/2020', transaction: "cell phone", amount: -127.35 },
        { id: 2, date: '1/3/2020', transaction: "car payment", amount: -303.97, },
      ],
      transactionData: this.withRunningTotals([
        {
          id: 0,
          date: '1/1/2020',
          transaction: "gas",
          amount: -35.45,
          runningTotal: null
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          date: '1/2/2020',
          transaction: "cell phone",
          amount: -227.35,
          runningTotal: null
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          date: '1/3/2020',
          transaction: "car payment",
          amount: -403.97,
          runningTotal: null
        },
      ]),
    }
  }

  withRunningTotals() {
    const { transactionData, startBal } = this.state;

    let running = startBal;
    return transactionData.map(el => {
      running += el.amount;
      return {
        ...el,
        runningTotal: running,
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Comment: I believe I tried that before I posted my question.  I received the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of null
Transactions
C:/Users/Daniel/projects/react-projects/checkbook-app/src/components/checking/transactions.js:9
   6 |      <td>{props.date} </td>
   7 |      <td>{props.transaction}</td>
   8 |      <td>{props.amount}</td>
>  9 |      <td>{props.runningTotal.toFixed(2)}</td>
     | ^  10 |    </tr>
  11 | 
  12 |  );`

Comment: That'll happen on the initial render. I would suggest changing the initial values for `runningTotal` from `null` to `0`, or moving the call of `addRunningTotal` to the constructor method and having it return the updated `transactionData` instead of calling `setState`.

Comment: Success!  That did it.  Thank you.  By "that" I mean that I changed the initial value from null to 0.  Am I right in assuming that once I connect this to a database, that whatever replaces runningTotal, or connects to runningTotal must also by an integer?

Comment: Yeah because `toFixed` is a method of the type `Number` so `null` or `String` don't have the `toFixed` method.

Comment: So, tell me, is it better way to directly use it at the front-end while rendering or use it at the back-end while saving the data in the database? which one is a better way?

Comment: @Aadi, in general, any sort of desired formatting should be performed as the last step, since this is just for display purposes and should not affect your storage (whether React state or in the database). Same reason why you don't store the whole render value as a string (just the underlying values). If you're storing money amounts (common case for `.toFixed(2)`) in a database, you'd do better to store values in cents (so that $1 would be 100 in the db) so you don't have to worry about rounding or floating-point issues (then on the frontend just do `(amount / 100).toFixed(2)`).